# Javascript Local vs Global Variables

Tags: javascript

I am trying to learn Javascript and was making a simple math question problem and was trying to make a function to score right answers and wrong answers, but I can't figure out how to pass any information out of my function to permanently keep a score.  Can anyone help me?

```html
<html>
<body>
<p id="question"></p>
<input id="answerBox" type=number>
<button onclick="checkAnswer()">Answer</button>
<p id="answer"></p>
<p id="score"></p>
<p id="newQuestion"></p>


<script>
//create MathAddition Problem;
var mathAdd = function(x, y) {
return x + " + " + y + " = "
}

//set random numbers;
var x = Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);
var y = Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);
var z = x + y
console.log(z)

//Call mathAdd function;
document.getElementById("question").innerHTML=mathAdd(x, y);


//Check Answer
var checkAnswer = function() {
var answer=document.getElementById("answerBox").value;
if(answer == z) {
document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML=answer + " is correct";
document.getElementById("score").innerHTML="Your score is improving" ;

}
else {
document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML=answer + " is not correct";
document.getElementById("score").innerHTML="Your score is dropping. Work harder!" ;
  }

document.getElementById("newQuestion").innerHTML="<a href='test7.html'>Next Question</a>"
}


</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please describe your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a variable `score` that increments each time the answer is correct. Something like this:

```
var score = 0;

//Check Answer
var checkAnswer = function() {
  var answer = document.getElementById("answerBox").value;
  if (answer == z) {
    score++;
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = answer + " is correct";
    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "Your score increased to " + score;
  }
  else {
    score--;
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = answer + " is not correct";
    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "Your score dropped to " + score + ". Work harder!" ;
  }

  document.getElementById("newQuestion").innerHTML = "<a href='test7.html'>Next Question</a>"
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I first tried. But since the score variable is increased only locally in the function, there is no permanent score.  When you go to "Next Question" score is reset to 0 as a global.

Comment: That shouldn't be the case, since all changes to `score` should be global. Now, I don't believe there is any way other than URL parameters or session state to forward variables across files (i.e. that `test7.html` file).